displaying image during sign up issue
Good evening,
I am currently having issue with displaying an image in my python chat app. I can get it working fine in part on another file but once I try to make it work in the original application it have errors. please help
Here is the original code:




'''

Let Chat 2.0

'''
import pika
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, simpledialog, colorchooser
from tkinter import \*
from tkinter.ttk import \*
import re
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class ChatApp:
def __init__(self):
self.usernames = set()
self.emails = {}
self.ages = set()
self.passwords = {}
self.current_username = None
self.text_colour = "#000000"  # Default color
self.connection, self.channel = self.connect_to_rabbitmq()
self.option()

    def connect_to_rabbitmq(self):
        try:
            connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
            channel = connection.channel()
            channel.queue_declare(queue='chat')
            return connection, channel
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Connection Error", str(e))
            exit()
    
    def send_message(self, username, message, colour):
        message = self.replace_text_with_emoji(message)
        full_message = f"{username}: {message}~{colour}"
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='chat', body=full_message)
        self.show_message(username, message, colour)
    
    def receive_messages(self, text_area):
        def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
            message = body.decode()
            # Split message and color (if color is added to the message)
            msg, colour = message.rsplit("~", 1)
            msg = self.replace_text_with_emoji(msg)
            # Update text area with the received message and color
            text_area.after(0, lambda: self.insert_colored_message(text_area, msg, colour))
            text_area.after(0, lambda: text_area.yview(tk.END))
    
        self.channel.basic_consume(queue='chat', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
        self.channel.start_consuming()
    
    def replace_text_with_emoji(self, message):
        emoji_map = {
            ":smile:": "",
            ":laugh:": "",
            ":heart:": "",
            ":thumbsup:": "",
        }
    
        for text, emoji in emoji_map.items():
            message = message.replace(text, emoji)
        return message
    
    def show_message(self, username, message, colour):
        print(f"{username}: {message} - {colour}")  # Just a print placeholder
    
    def on_send(self, entry, username, colour, text_area):
        message = entry.get()
        if message:
            self.send_message(username, message, colour)
            entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    
    def option(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.title('Let Chat')
        root.geometry('350x200')
    
        style = Style()
        style.configure('TButton', font=('calibri', 20), borderwidth='4')
    
        Button(root, text='Sign In', command=self.sign_in).grid(row=1, column=3, pady=10, padx=100)
        Button(root, text='Sign Up', command=self.sign_up).grid(row=2, column=3, pady=10, padx=100)
        Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).grid(row=3, column=3, pady=10, padx=100)
    
        root.mainloop()
    
    def sign_up(self):
        form = tk.Tk()
        form.title("Let Chat - Sign Up")
    
        tk.Label(form, text="Username:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        UserEntry = tk.Entry(form)
        UserEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
    
        tk.Label(form, text="Email:").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        EmailEntry = tk.Entry(form)
        EmailEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
    
        tk.Label(form, text="Age:").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        AgeEntry = tk.Entry(form)
        AgeEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
    
        tk.Label(form, text="Password:").grid(row=3, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        PasswordEntry = tk.Entry(form, show="*")
        PasswordEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
        
        # Function to select and display image
        def select_image():
            file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                title="Select an Image",
                filetypes=[("Image Files", "*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.gif")]
            )
            print(f"Selected file path: {file_path}")
    
            if file_path:
                try:
                    img = Image.open(file_path)
                    print(f"Image opened successfully: {file_path}")
                    img = img.resize((300, 300))
                    img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    
                    if hasattr(select_image, "current_img_label"):
                        select_image.current_img_label.destroy()
    
                    select_image.current_img_label = tk.Label(form, image=img_tk)
                    select_image.current_img_label.image = img_tk
                    select_image.current_img_label.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)
    
                    # Explicitly set a reference to the image object in the window object
                    form.image_ref = img_tk
                    print("Image displayed successfully")
    
                except Exception as e:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Unable to open image: {e}")
                    print(f"Error opening image: {e}")
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("No file", "No image selected")
                print("No image selected")
    
        select_image_button = tk.Button(form, text="Select Profile Image", command=select_image)
        select_image_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=15)
    
        def create_account():
            username = UserEntry.get()
            email = EmailEntry.get()
            age = AgeEntry.get()
            password = PasswordEntry.get()
    
            if username in self.usernames:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Username already taken.")
            elif not re.match(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$", email):
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid email format.")
            elif email in self.emails:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Email already taken.")
            elif not age.isdigit() or int(age) < 18:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Must be 18 or older.")
            elif not re.match(r"^([a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$", password):
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Password must be at least 8 characters and include a number and special character.")
            else:
                self.usernames.add(username)
                self.emails[email] = username
                self.ages.add(age)
                self.passwords[email] = password
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"You are signed up as {username}")
                form.destroy()
    
        tk.Button(form, text="Sign Up", command=create_account).grid(columnspan=3, padx=15, pady=15)
        form.mainloop()
    
    def sign_in(self):
        form = tk.Tk()
        form.title("Let Chat - Sign In")
    
        tk.Label(form, text="Email:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        EmailEntry = tk.Entry(form)
        EmailEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
    
        tk.Label(form, text="Password:").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        PasswordEntry = tk.Entry(form, show="*")
        PasswordEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
    
        def check_credentials():
            email = EmailEntry.get()
            password = PasswordEntry.get()
    
            if email not in self.emails:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Email not registered.")
            elif self.passwords.get(email) != password:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Incorrect password.")
            else:
                self.current_username = self.emails[email]
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Signed in successfully!")
                form.destroy()
                self.chat_room(self.current_username)
    
        tk.Button(form, text="Sign In", command=check_credentials).grid(columnspan=1, padx=15, pady=15)
        form.mainloop()
    
    def chat_room(self, username):
        chat_buddy = simpledialog.askstring("Welcome " + username, "Enter the Username of who you want to chat with:")
        if chat_buddy:
            self.setup_gui(username, chat_buddy)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Username cannot be empty")
    
    def setup_gui(self, username, chat_buddy):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Let Chat - " + username + " Is Chatting with " + chat_buddy)
    
        text_area = tk.Text(root, bg="#F0F0F0", fg="#000000", font=("Helvetica", 12), wrap='word')
        text_area.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    
        entry = tk.Entry(root, bg="#D3D3D3", font=("Helvetica", 12))
        entry.pack(padx=10, pady=(0, 10), fill=tk.X)
    
        # Button to send message
        send_button = tk.Button(root, text="Send", font=("Helvetica", 12), command=lambda: self.on_send(entry, username, self.text_colour, text_area))
        send_button.pack(pady=(1, 10))
    
        feature_frame = tk.Frame(root)
        feature_frame.pack(pady=(2, 10))
    
        # Emoji buttons (unchanged)
        smile_button = tk.Button(feature_frame, text="", font=("Helvetica", 12), command=lambda: self.insert_emoji(entry, ""))
        smile_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
    
        laugh_button = tk.Button(feature_frame, text="", font=("Helvetica", 12), command=lambda: self.insert_emoji(entry, ""))
        laugh_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
    
        heart_button = tk.Button(feature_frame, text="", font=("Helvetica", 12), command=lambda: self.insert_emoji(entry, ""))
        heart_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
    
        thumbsup_button = tk.Button(feature_frame, text="", font=("Helvetica", 12), command=lambda: self.insert_emoji(entry, ""))
        thumbsup_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
    
        # Button to choose text color
        color_button = tk.Button(feature_frame, text="Choose Color", font=("Helvetica", 12), command=lambda: self.change_text_colour(entry))
        color_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)
    
        threading.Thread(target=self.receive_messages, args=(text_area,), daemon=True).start()
    
        self.setup_tags(text_area)
    
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        root.mainloop()
    
    def insert_emoji(self, entry, emoji):
        entry.insert(tk.END, emoji)
    
    def change_text_colour(self, entry):
        # Open color chooser dialog and set the color
        color_code = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]  # Returns a tuple (rgb, hex)
        if color_code:
            self.text_colour = color_code  # Store selected color
    
    def setup_tags(self, text_area):
        # Set up text tags for colors
        text_area.tag_configure("msg", foreground="#000000")  # Default black text
        text_area.tag_configure("colored", foreground=self.text_colour)  # Default color
    
    def insert_colored_message(self, text_area, msg, colour):
        text_area.insert(tk.END, msg + "\n", "colored")
        text_area.tag_add("colored", "1.0", "end")
        text_area.tag_configure("colored", foreground=colour)
    
    def on_closing(self):
        self.connection.close()  # Close RabbitMQ connection
        root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
ChatApp()





Here is the working in parts one:




import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def sign_up():form = tk.Tk()form.title("Let Chat - Sign Up")

    # Username
    tk.Label(form, text="Username:").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
    user_entry = tk.Entry(form)
    user_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
    
    # Email
    tk.Label(form, text="Email:").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
    email_entry = tk.Entry(form)
    email_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
    
    # Age
    tk.Label(form, text="Age:").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
    age_entry = tk.Entry(form)
    age_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
    
    # Password
    tk.Label(form, text="Password:").grid(row=3, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)
    password_entry = tk.Entry(form, show="*")
    password_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
    
    # Function to select and display image
    def select_image():
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            title="Select an Image",
            filetypes=[("Image Files", "*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.gif")]
        )
        print(f"Selected file path: {file_path}")
    
        if file_path:
            try:
                img = Image.open(file_path)
                print(f"Image opened successfully: {file_path}")
                img = img.resize((400, 300))
                img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    
                if hasattr(select_image, "current_img_label"):
                    select_image.current_img_label.destroy()
    
                select_image.current_img_label = tk.Label(form, image=img_tk)
                select_image.current_img_label.image = img_tk
                select_image.current_img_label.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)
    
                # Explicitly set a reference to the image object in the window object
                form.image_ref = img_tk
                print("Image displayed successfully")
    
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Unable to open image: {e}")
                print(f"Error opening image: {e}")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("No file", "No image selected")
            print("No image selected")
    
    select_image_button = tk.Button(form, text="Select Profile Image", command=select_image)
    select_image_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=15)
    
    def submit():
        username = user_entry.get()
        email = email_entry.get()
        age = age_entry.get()
        password = password_entry.get()
        # Process these variables (e.g., save to a database, validation, etc.)
    
    submit_button = tk.Button(form, text="Submit", command=submit)
    submit_button.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=15)
    
    form.mainloop()

# Call the function to start the application

sign_up()





I have try many ways to fix it but it never work or I get another error.
I am it to work like the working one but with all of the other function of my current application.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the errors in your post.

The issue is due to multiple instances of Tk().  Use Toplevel() instead for windows other than the root window.  Also avoid calling .mainloop() more than once.

You're having too many typo errors
